# How to create a Chrome profile programmatically?

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, automation, user-accounts, user-profile

Development, testing, staging environments are controlled via different proxy servers in my setup. I want to script creation of multiple Chrome profiles (sometimes called "user" or "person") and connect to a different proxy server for each of them. Finally I want to share this script with colleagues so that they have access to the exactly same setup.

The latter can be done via scripted installation of extensions such as [Falcon Proxy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/falcon-proxy/gchhimlnjdafdlkojbffdkogjhhkdepf) or [Proxy Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-helper/mnloefcpaepkpmhaoipjkpikbnkmbnic) to the Chrome profile. I would like to know how to script creation of the different profiles.

A profile is a folder inside `~/.config/google-chrome` (Linux, `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome` (Mac OS X) and `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` (Windows). But how to create and initialize one? Where do I register the new profile?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Creating a user

The following example applies to Windows, but the basic procedure should be the same.

First, change to the UserData folder in your Chrome installation:

```
cd "%APPDATA%\..\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"
```

This method will copy the current user as a template for the new user. If the new user should be blank, you need to delete (`CTRL + SHIFT + DEL` the current browser data).

Now create a new user:

```
mkdir NewUser && copy Default NewUser
```

Change your directory to the chrome installation:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"
```

Factory-Reset all user parameters:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="..\User Data\NewUser" -first-run
```

where `--user-data-dir` is the path (full or relative) to the previously created NewUser directory.

### Running as NewUser

To run chrome again using this profile, simply run chrome without the `-first-run` flag.

Comment: This doesn't seem what I need. If I created a second "user data dir", I will need to run another copy of Chrome to load it. Instead, Chrome has a feature to create multiple `People` (http://www.howtogeek.com/207614/everything-you-need-to-know-about-google-chromes-profile-switcher/) in the preferences so that I can switch to a different person easily.

Comment: Great answer. You don't even have to pre-create the folder or copy data into it.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly! When you click on ' .url ' links, the default Chrome profile opens. Editing the registry doesn't help. Chrome removes changes when it updates. Multiple chrome profiles are a joke! If you need a real profile, for example a profile on a memory disk, then my choice is 'mozilla'.

Answer (score 12):

From this [documentation](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), I finally found a way to create a user/person, rather than a separate profile. The difference is especially important in Mac OS X since different profiles can be opened concurrently using the same Chrome process.

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --profile-directory="StagingEnv" --first-run`

The only unfortunate fact is that this new person doesn't inherit the name from the profile directory. Instead, it is always called `Person X` where X is an increment number.

I need to go to the `Local State` file to change it.

`grep -o '"StagingEnv":{[^}]*}' ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Local\ State`

`"StagingEnv":{"active_time":1437709453.172762,"avatar_icon":"chrome://theme/IDR_PROFILE_AVATAR_6","background_apps":false,"is_ephemeral":false,"is_omitted_from_profile_list":false,"is_using_default_avatar":true,"is_using_default_name":true,"managed_user_id":"","name":"<b>Person 3</b>","user_name":""}`

This file is overridden when Chrome quits, so I need to kill Chrome, change the file and run Chrome again.

Answer (score -4):

I think the easiest way to create multiple chrome profile is

- On your computer, open Chrome.
- At the top right, click `Profile`.
- Click `Manage people`.
- Click `Add person`.
- Choose a name and a photo/picture.
- Select `Create a short cut on the desktop`.
- Click `Save`. A new window will open and ask you to turn on sync which is
  optional.

By this, each chrome profile will be created and you can check on `C:\Users\youname\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`.

Comment: The question is about creating profiles _programmatically_