# How to add a new person to Google Chrome with batch or Powershell?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

I am tasked on creating a new chrome profile with a specific for all employees of the company, and the task proves allot more difficult than one would expect it to be.

I started scouting the web and came across allot of guides that basically said the same thing,
[How to create a Chrome profile programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31067404/how-to-create-a-chrome-profile-programmatically)

So I replicated the script to my own needs (later on, I will change the script from copying another profile on the pc, to copying a profile from a shared drive)

```
## moving to the chrome directory
cd "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data"

## copying the new profile
mkdir "Profile 2" && copy "Profile 1"



## moving to chrome installation directory
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"

## Reseting and launching new profile
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\User Data\NewUser" -first-run
```

My findings, were, that the profile is successfully created, but when I open Chrome from that profile, other profiles seem to be missing, and when I open chrome normally, I don't see the new profile, as if it was a brand new installation of Chrome.

This is what I see when I open chrome normally (TEST being Profile 1, test3 being Profile 3 on the chrome local appdata folder)
[Profile list when Chrome is opened normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjagN.png)

And this is what I see when I open the new profile in Chrome (using the last line in the script) (this is Profile 2 in the chrome directory)
[Profile list when I open the new profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUT4s.png) See how the 'other people' section is missing the other profiles